# Regex for File Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file name like `Sample File_20140408201420(20140409_0).xlsx`

And I have set pattern as `'Sample File'+ @"(.*)\.xlsx"` in my C# code but regex matching isnt working. 20140408201420(20140409_0) is the part whihc will change based on file name.

What is the correct Regex Pattern I should be using ?

Comment: buddy actually i dont see a problem with your code, it should wrk fine. can you post other parts of your code. that may make things more clear

Comment: I have a folder watcher which will pick the file based on regex and it is returning 0 file with this pattern.

Comment: Is 'Sample File' in single- or double-quotes in your code? And what does the file watcher part of the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
static Regex rxFileNamePattern = new Regex( @"
  ^           # anchor the match at start-of-text, followed by
  Sample File # the literal "Sample File", followed by
  \d+         # 1 or more decimal digits, followed by
  \(          # a literal left/open parenthesis "(", followed by
  \d+         # 1 or more decimal digits, followed by
  _           # a literal underscore "_", followed by
  \d+         # 1 or more decimal digits, followed by
  \)          # a literal right/close parenthesis ")", followed by
  \.xlsx      # the literal ".xlsx", followed by
  $           # end-of-text
  " , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // First we see the input string.
    string input = "Sample File_20140408201420(20140409_0).xlsx";

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"Sample File_(.*)\.xlsx",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
        string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
    }
}
```

what I have done ?

I have changed the regex to :

```
@"Sample File_(.*)\.xlsx"
```

this will return the value :

```
20140408201420(20140409_0)
```

i guess this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `Regex`:

```
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp").Where(path => Regex.Match(path, @"Sample File_[0-9]{14}(.*)\.xlsx").Success);
```

If you don't care about the amount of number, you can try this:

```
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp").Where(path => Regex.Match(path, @"Sample File_(.*)\.xlsx").Success);
```